# getAsync("key").get(timeout, sec) doesn't wait, return null

Tags: java, scala, hazelcast

Hazelcast 3.4.4.
I got a situation when `map.getAsync` returns null no matter what. It even if timeout set to `10000000`, `TimeUnit.SECONDS` it doesn't wait.

But if I put `Thread.sleep(10000)` just before getAsync then it returns proper value from the map.

I wonder what's wrong and how I could check/fix/undersand it?

***UPDATE***: if I remove `import ExecutionContext.Implicit.global` from my code and all dependencies (like `Scala.concurent.Future`), then getAsync starts working again. But I'm not satisfied still ...

Comment: What happens if you call `future.get()` with no timeout? Same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it feels like you expect it to wait until a value is put into the map, doesn't it?

It doesn't mean that it will wait until a value becomes available, it just gives you the option to have a timeout for the case the cluster is totally exhausted and cannot answer your request fast enough.

I actually think there is no good way to achieve what you're looking for but you could use the local EntryListeners, waiting for a key and forward the event through a topic, if that makes sense. You might also need a Promise kind of implementation.

Comment: I guess in the context of implementing Promise I could make use of lock by key before actually put it to the map. So then the client who want access it would wait UNTIL lock is released. And it will be released after put is done its work wrapped by /in  promise. Is that fair thinking? Then I may avoid using EntryListeners

Comment: Well you would have to force and unlock since the client is the lock owner, probably not the cleanest way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's an issue with 3.4.4, but 3.5.1 works (from REPL):

```
scala> import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent._

scala> import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> val map = hz.getMap[String, Int]("map")
map: com.hazelcast.core.IMap[String,Int] = IMap{name='map'}

scala> map.set("one", 1)

scala> map.getAsync("one").get()
res4: Int = 1
```

Comment: Now I beleive it is not about Execution Context but about the way getAsync work. Just when I wrap putAsync in my Future it turns out that it works a little slower when that future starts and getAsync gets null because the value is not in the map yet. So getAsync doesn't wait for value to come. It waits for get to get whatever it would able to get at present moment

Comment: @ses, correct, async is for non-blocking operations. If the map doesn't contain the key, neither will the future.
You should look at `IMap.addEntryListener`.

Comment: I guess with addEntry I would suffer with bad performance if I add many items to the map. Since it would trigger event for each add.

Comment: You can add a listener for a specific key, which seems to be your use case. `addEntryListener(MapListener listener, K key, boolean includeValue)`